# Want to install webpack-cli

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I want to install webpack, but it gives me an error: `webpack-cli@3.2.1 postinstall: lightercollective`. How to install it success?

Comment: do webpack-cli --v. To check if it is installed since it gives post installation errors

Comment: `webpack-cli: command not found` :(

Comment: giveup on webpack-cli and try webpack-nano. I've gave up on it when it started to get big.

Comment: Can you post the entire command you're running and its output?

Comment: i running `$ npm install webpack webpack-cli`, but output: `sh: lightercollective: command not found, npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! webpack-cli@3.2.1 postinstall: lightercollective
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the webpack-cli@3.2.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`

Comment: Try running `npm install lightercollective && npm install webpack webpack-cli`. The problem is that you don't have lightercollective installed. The error is probably from a post-install hook in webpack. Hopefully, if you install lightercollective first, the problem goes away.

Comment: it didn't help me, showing `sh: lightercollective not found` error

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this issue lately as well. It looks like they introduced a peer dependency on `lightercollective` in a minor/patch version of webpack.

I got the exact same error message, however I noticed that the process did not exit (it just got stuck after the error). If I wait a while (like maybe 5-15 minutes) it appears something times out, and the webpack build continues after the error message, and outputs all assets as usual.

After I installed `lightercollective` (`npm install --save lightercollective`) the error dissappeared and I no longer have to wait for the timeout for my build to complete.

Comment: I'm installing lightercollective, it's ok, but when I try to install webpack-CLI, it gives me an error `lightercollective: command not found`

Comment: what OS have you?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to verify that you have installed last version of Node.js and npm?

```
node -v / npm -v
```

Seems that you had installed globally only webpack and not webpack-cli or inverse.

Then install webpack and webpack-cli globally

```
npm uninstall -g webpack webpack-cli
npm install -g webpack webpack-cli
```

Comment: node - 8.11.3, npm - 6.5.0. Glogal install gives me error(

Answer (score 0):

We don't use `lightercollective` now at `webpack-cli`. You shouldn't experience this issue as of now. Just upgrade `webpack-cli` to the latest version.